# Find all possible paths from child to top level parent

Tags: c#, graph

[My graph looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFyHZ.png)

How to find all  possible paths from child to top level parent in a graph in c#?  I have a single top parent in the graph. All nodes have own id, name and parent id. The topmost level parent has parentid zero and a child can have multiple parents.
[I have to find all paths from H to A as
HEBA,HGDA AND HECA
My node is as below.

```
    class Node
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<int> ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: What data structure do you use to represent the digraph?

Comment: @Thomas I've update question.

Comment: @Codor I've updated the question.

Comment: a child can have multiple parents:  then your struct does not work. public int ParentId { get; set; } has to be an array/list. Or I don't get your question correct

Comment: @Thomas yes you are right. It's a list.

Answer (score 0):

you can find out all paths from 1 child to the top level parent, with a BFS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search or also a DFS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search.
Both can be written recursively and iteratively. But be careful, when you have a loop like Node1 -> Node2 -> Node1 then these algorithms never return

If you are searching for the fastes way you can also use dijkstra: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra-Algorithmus

Comment: I could not store the paths.Could you give me a sample?

Comment: Danke aber das ist in Deutsch.

Comment: sorry... here is the English link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm